# Use only the Data Layer from Meteor.JS

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Meteor.JS is a full-stack framework, but I'm only interested in its Data Layer.

Things like - the Browser local MongoDB implementation, Browser to Server MongoDB synchronisation, Subscriptions and Live Queries.

Is there a project that **extract all this into separate package** maybe? Or maybe there's some other MongoDB JS project doing same things?

I want to use that data layer with Svelte or React.JS, connected in a custom way.

Comment: Do you intend to use the Meteor internals in an external framework?

Comment: It's possible, but not easy. What exactly do you want to achieve? Meteor works with Svelte and React already. I have seen projects that replace the build system with Webpack, if that helps?

Comment: @FredStark yes, I will try to find such projects and see how it works.

Comment: @Jankapunkt yes, the Meteor data layer with other libraries, without anything else from meteor.